# combine data from two different tables in hive

Tags: hive

I need to combine data from two different tables in hive.Its like cbind in R.I have a table with one column like:

patient_data

```
patient_id
   5
   25
   563
```

and

probable_data

```
 prob
  .25
  .69
  .67
```

I need to do:

```
patient_id    probable_data
   5               .25
   25              .69
   563             .67
```

I have tried

```
 SELECT patient_data.patient_id,probable_data.prob FROM patient_data,probable_data;
```

but i am getting error

FAILED: ParseException line 3:19 missing EOF at ',' near 'patients_check'

How could it be done in hive.
Thanks

Comment: Your input data seem to have a problem. Apart from that, how are you going to connect patient_data with probable_data, is there any rule for it?

Comment: @Ashalynd:I just need to have data with two columns one patient_id and other probable_data

Answer (score 0):

Although the command you wrote should work:

```
 SELECT patient_data.patient_id,probable_data.prob FROM patient_data,probable_data;
```

but try to get red of the `patient.` and `probable_data.` so your command will look like

```
 SELECT patient_id, prob FROM patient_data, probable_data;
```

And to join the data do

```
hive> SELECT patient_data.patient_id, probable_data.prob
      >FROM patient_di JOIN patient_data ON patient_data.patient_id = probable_data.prob;
```

You might need to put `patient_data.patient_id = probable_data.prob` as `(patient_data.patient_id = probable_data.prob)` in both cases it worked for  me.

Comment: from patient_di?  that is not a table